# Approximating $\sqrt x$ using Heron's method vs. Taylor's method

Tags: calculus, polynomials, taylor-expansion, approximation

let's say I want to approximate $f(x)=\sqrt x$ using an "old" method (whatever that means): where:

$y^2\leq x$

or

$y \leq \sqrt x$

$\sqrt x \approx \frac y2 + \frac{x}{2y}$

With remainder R such that

$\frac{-(x-y^2)^2}{8y^3} \leq R \leq 0$

I'm supposed to explain this method,  using Taylor Polynomials.

A Taylor polynomial of degree 2 of $\sqrt x$, say evaluated at 100, and x = 101 would be

$\sqrt 101 \approx P_2(101)=10 + \frac{1}{20}(101-100)-\frac{1}{2000}(101-100)^2$

$\sqrt 101 \approx P_2(101)=\frac{201}{20}-\frac{1}{2000}=\frac{20099}{2000}\approx \sqrt101$

I skipped the calculations as it belongs to the previous question. Now,  what I don't see is how these two are related. I see that the error term "R" is in some interval..

Any hints?

Comment: The "old" method is called "Heron-Verfahren" (in german), in English probably called "Heron-method".

Comment: Hint concerning the taylor-series : Start with $x=y^2+z$ and expand $\sqrt{1+\frac{z}{y^2}}$ into a taylor-series. (Consider : $\sqrt{x}=y\cdot \sqrt{1+\frac{z}{y^2}}$)

Comment: Sorry, but where did you get the $z$? Is that the unknown part that's between $[a,x]$ ? Often called $s$?

Comment: $\sqrt x = P_n(x)=\sqrt{{y^2}+{z}} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y^2}+{z}}(x-a)$? I think I misunderstood you about what is a and what is x in the formula